# Training Multi Class Image classification model

Tags: tensorflow, model, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am trying to create a model using Tensorflow and Python, I get the data from a folder on my pc

[The Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLDHJ.jpg)

[An Example from the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObOWb.jpg)

Almost all data are the same size [237 items,223 items,495 items,387 items,301 items]

That's how I load my data:

```
lables = {'Basic T-shrit':0, 'Bikini Bottom':1, 'Cargo Pants':2, 'Jeans':3, 'Oversize T-Shirt':4}
#Data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/256)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'Dataset',  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(256, 256),  # All images will be resized to 200 x 200
        batch_size=batch_size,
        # Specify the classes explicitly
        classes = lables,
        # Since we use categorical_crossentropy loss, we need categorical labels
        class_mode='categorical')
```

That's a model I tried:

```
#Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(image_width,image_height,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32,3,3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(categorys_size, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['acc'])
```

Then I start the learning process:

```
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                steps_per_epoch=epoch_steps,
                epochs=Epoch,
                validation_data=train_generator)
```

But it's not working good, The model sees the oversize shirt and normal shirt the same and any kind of pants as jeans

[Model Train result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NadmU.jpg)

Then I tested this model:

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.22), 
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(4, 4), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.15),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis = 1),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.15),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),    
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    #keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu,kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
    #keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
    keras.layers.Dense(len(lables), activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax)])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I start learning:

```
#Start Learning
checkpoint_path="/chk/cp-{epoch:04d}.ckpt"
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path, 
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1,
                                                 period=10)
model.fit(train,
          epochs=Epoch,callbacks = [cp_callback],
          validation_data=val,verbose=1)
```

And that's how I load the data

```
    data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Dataset',labels = 'inferred',image_size = (192,192))  
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()          
batch = data_iterator.next()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch[1][idx])
#Scale Data
data = data.map(lambda x,y: (x/192, y))
data.as_numpy_iterator().next()
    
train_size = int(len(data)*.7)
val_size = int(len(data)*.2)
test_size = int(len(data)*.1)
print(train_size)
train = data.take(train_size)
val = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test = data.skip(train_size+val_size).take(test_size)
```

What I am doing wrong? and is the data I collected good enough for what I am trying to do? Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: It is not necessary that you are doing anything wrong, have you considered that maybe the classes are very visually similar?

Comment: Maybe this can be the case for the pants but something like oversize t shirt and normal t shirt there's is a huge difference visually, Also something like the bikini is never recognizable by the model and it's different from anything in the dataset

Comment: What does it mean when you say it doesn't work well? What is accuracy? What does the validation and training loss look like during training? Is the validation/training accuracy increasing during training? Without the information, we can only guess.

Comment: @LadislavOndris, Updated my question with the train result, For example after this train when i give it Cargo Pants it returns Oversize shirt ... If I gave it human face or something it also returns Cargo Pants

Comment: You shouldn't be using your training data as validation. You want to split your dataset so that the model is evaluated during training on data it wasn't trained on. Once you have that, you can easily spot whether the model is overfitting. It seems to me that your dataset is really small to train a NN. If you're only experimenting with neural nets, I suggest you find a larger dataset, such as Fashion MNIST. But if you particularly need your model to work on your dataset, use a pre-trained model.

Comment: I see that you divide the dataset into train and val parts only in the second example. The output you provided was for the first or the second example?

Comment: @LadislavOndris okay I will increase my dataset and make a different one for validation, I can't use Fashion MNIST since i want to use this model in my app and it will include ads and that's disagrees with terms of usage, What do you mean by pre-trained model ?, The output i provided was for the first Model and the output almost the same on the 2 Models but Keras model '2nd one' is way off and almost every prediction is wrong, How much data do you think is enough for this kind of model ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED A pre-trained model is a model that has already been trained on large datasets. Their advantage is that they can recognize basic shapes. You typically take this model and just fine-tune it on your dataset. You save time during training and also improve accuracy. The model can also better generalize. Because the model has already been trained, your dataset for fine-tuning can be much smaller because the model doesn't have to learn basic features from scratch. Reading this page should give you a better idea: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: When you train from scratch, you typically need thousands of examples of each class in your dataset. Of course, the number depends on several factors, but seeing just a few hundred seems to little. That said, I would give a pre-trained model a shot.

Comment: @LadislavOndris Great to know, Is there's any fashion pre trained model on your mind I can try it ?

Comment: @LadislavOndris while researching i found that Object detection does not need all this images for training so do you suggest going this path ?

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED you don't need the model to be explicitly pre-trained on fashion. The idea is that the model can recognize basic features in the image. The first layer typically recognizes edges, the next one combines those edges into textures, and so on until the highest layer where is capable of recognizing complex objects. You can use any model that was pre-trained on images. These models are universal. That's why you also need to fine-tune it on your dataset. You can use ResNet, MobileNet, etc: See TF Hub: https://tfhub.dev/s?deployment-format=lite&module-type=image-classification

Comment: @YOUSEF-ELSAYED Do not confuse object detection with image classification. Object detection predicts both location and class of an object in an image (typically multiple objects in a single image), while image classification predicts a single class for the given object (which is your case).